# Some question on haar measure for sumsets of closed subsets of profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, haar-measure, sumsets

Let $H$ be a profinite group with the haar measure $\mu_H$. Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be closed subgroups of $H$. $H_1$ and $H_2$ have their own haar measures $\mu_{H_1}$ and $\mu_{H_2}$ respectively.

Suppose $\mu_H(H_1H_2)>0$, where $H_1H_2:=\{h_1h_2|\ h_1\in H_1, h_2\in H_2\}$.

My question is as follows : For two closed subsets $A_1\subset H_1$ and $A_2\subset H_2$ with $\mu_{H_1}(A_1)>0$ and $\mu_{H_2}(A_2)>0$, is it the case that $\mu_{H}(A_1A_2)>0$, where $A_1A_2:=\{a_1a_2|\ a_1\in A_1,a_2\in A_2\}$?

Comment: what is the question? Do you wish to know if $\mu _H(A_1A_2)>0$? In that case please edit the question. This question is indeed answered below

Comment: As suggested by @Venkataramana, I significantly edited the question in a direction that makes it ask the only question I could see that might make sense. And then the answer below is a good answer.

Comment: I'd like to know whether $\mu_H(A_1A_2)>0$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Consider $H_1H_2$ as a subset of $H$. This is a $H_1\times H_2$ homogeneous space (for left-times-right action). On such a space there is a unique (up to scale) $H_1\times H_2$-invariant measure. But in our case we see obvious two ones: the restriction of $\mu_H$ and the push foreward of $\mu_{H_1}\times \mu_{H_2}$. Thus these two conicide, and the answer follows.

Comment: This argument isn't right. The restriction of $\mu_H$ could be the zero measure (and frequently is, I think).

Comment: @HJRW Could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Well, the claim that there's a unique invariant measure is clearly false, since we can scale. There should be lots of examples in which the Haar measure of a double-coset is zero.  For instance, the double coset of two pro-cyclic subgroups of a profinite free group should have infinitely many disjoint translates, and hence have zero Haar measure.

Comment: @HJRW, it indeed should be written "unique up to scale" instead of "unique". Thanks for this correction. I didn't elaborate, as this is a nearly trivial extension, but one could (and should) actually replace any reference to measure (in the question and in the answer) with measure class. In this form the answer applies as well to any locally compact group $H$. I guess this is why I haven't write "up to scale" in the first case. Anyway, I will update.

Comment: @HJRW, edited as promised. It came to my mind: maybe you missed reading the condition $\mu_H(H_1H_2)>0$ given in thecquestion.

Comment: @user89334,  sorry, you're quite right, I did miss that hypothesis. I withdraw my objection!  (As Paul Garrett notes above, the first incarnation of the question wasn't especially clear.)

Comment: @user89334 Thank you a lot! Let me summarize by myself again. In this case, $\mu_H$ and $\mu_{H_1}\times \mu_{H_2}$ are coincide up to scale. So this implies that $\mu_H(A_1A_2)=\mu_{H_1}(A_1)\mu_{H_2}(A_2)$ is positive. Am I right?

Comment: Luke, this not exactly what I wrote. I claim that $\mu_H|_{H_1H_2}$ coinsides (up to scale) with the push of $\mu_{H_1}\times \mu_{H_2}$ under the map $H_1\times H_2 \to H_1H_2$, $(h_1,h_2)\mapsto h_1h_2$. The two measures appearing in your comment are not defined on the same space.

Comment: @user89334 Ah I see. Then, $\mu_H(A_1A_2)=\mu_{H_1}\times \mu_{H_2}(m^{-1}(A_1A_2))$(up to scale), where $m:\ (h_1,h_2)\mapsto h_1h_2$ and since $m^{-1}(A_1A_2)$ contains $A_1\times A_2$, we are done! Wow!

Comment: Right. So the powerful thing we have used is this uniqueness of invariant measure on homogeneous spaces. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: @user89334 Frankly speaking, I'm not familiar with this. My motivation of this question comes from some model theoretic and geometric question on profinite group action. By the way, would you recommend some references on measure on homogeneous spaces?

Comment: For the uniqueness (up to scale) observe that for two invariant measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ both are absolutely continuous wrt $\mu=\mu_1+\mu_2$, hence $\mu_i=f_i\mu$ by Radon-Nikodym. $f_i$ are easily seen to be invariant, so both $\mu_i$ are proportional to $\mu$.

Comment: For a reference I am not sure. Try maybe Folland, abstract harmonic analysis. I used it for teaching once and it went quite well. I recall one of  the first chapters deals with this, but I was not focusing at such issues at the time. But you better ask others - I am not too good with references.

Comment: @user89334 Thank you so much. I really owe you a lot. I'm sorry not to be able to contact you. I hope you have a great day!